# Name of a shape that is intersected once by each ray that starts at a given point

Tags: terminology, convex-analysis, definition, geometry

Is there a particular name for a shape that is intersected exactly once by each ray that starts at a given point?

To illustrate: I'm looking for a name for shapes like the left one in this image:

[image: ShapeName]

(This is for 2D, but the same could be applied to surfaces in higher dimensions)

I thought about a word describing the shape and its relation to the point, for example, that the shape is *"convex referring to a single point"*, but this does not seem to be appropriate. One could possibly just call it a *"circle (or sphere) with varying radius"*; does anyone know if there is a more adequate name for this?

Comment: called star-shaped

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain

Comment: @mfl: Want to turn that into an answer? Since the question is mostly asking for a name, finding a name (or in fact four names) together with a reasonable reference is about the best kinf of answer you can get.

Comment: @MvG I have just done it following your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set that you describe is the **boundary of a star-shaped domain** (also called *star domain, star-convex set* and *radially convex set*). The formal definition is as follows:

A set $S$ in the Euclidean space is said to be star-shaped if there exists some point $x_0\in S$ such that for any $x\in S$ the line segment $x_0x$ is contained in $S.$

See the following link for more information:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_domain

Since you consider only the curve (or surface) limiting such a set, the usual is the boundary of the set.

See

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boundary_%28topology%29

for more information about the boundary of a set.

Comment: I thought that there might be a term more focussing on the *point*: The definition of the Star Domain only states that there exists **some** point [...]. But one can probably just describe the set as "a radially convex set *for* a given point", so this indeed seems to be what I have been looking for (+1, accepted - Thanks!)